# Concatenate in JavaScript with + gives extra comma if value is null

Tags: javascript

Here when I concatenate three different value with comma separator then if value is null then  comma is concatenate. How can I avoid extra comma if the value is null?

Below is the code I've tried.

```
var forecast = (is_forecast_checked()) ? 'f' : '';

var contract_volume = (is_contract_volume_checked()) ? 'd' : '';

var actual_volume = (is_actual_volume_checked()) ? 'a' : '';

var volume_type = forecast + ',' + contract_volume + ',' + actual_volume ;
```

Comment: Computers do what you tell them. You're telling it to do this. Use an `if` statement and tell it to do something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple

```
var forecast = (is_forecast_checked() ? 'f' : ''),
// add the comma here if its not null
    contract_volume = (is_contract_volume_checked() ? ',d' : ''),
// same here
    actual_volume = (is_actual_volume_checked() ? ',a' : ''),
// remove the comma concatenation
// replace unwanted, double commas, preceding or ending commas
    volume_type = (forecast + contract_volume + actual_volume).replace(/$,|^,|\B,/g,'');
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. If they are all true then you get "f,,d,,a"

Comment: First is true so I get an "f". Then because it wasn't null I "add the comma here" which gives "f," . Then I add a ",d" which gives "f,,d" etc

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
var array = [];

is_forecast_checked() && array.push("f");
is_contract_volume_checked() && array.push("d");
is_actual_volume_checked() && array.push("a");

volume_type = array.join(",");
```

Comment: this is clearly overkill... your adding 4 extra function calls here and that would only make sense if it was in a loop